# Calendar Class problems

Tags: java, calendar

I am having problems with the `Calendar` Class.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance ();

int iYear  = cal.get (Calendar.YEAR);         // get the current year

int iMonth = cal.get (Calendar.MONTH);        // month...

int iDay   = cal.get (Calendar.); // current day in the month
```

This... No Workie!! :-(

I used the debugger and found that the YEAR and the DAY_OF_MONTH are correct, 
however, the MONTH is 1 (January) when it SHOULD BE 2 (February).

Here is where it gets even more WEIRD:

I then tried `cal.clear ();`

followed by `cal.set (2014, 2, 27); // Today's Date - Feb 27, 2014`

and the month was still 1 (i.e. January)

I set the date to days in January, (2014, 1, 1), (2014, 1, 16),etc
It correctly gave me a 1 for the month

After reading and trying many things (and pulling my hair out..)
I set it to a date in the future, my Birthday (2014, 5, 23) and other days.
For those dates, Month was correctly set to 5 (May)

Comment: Thanx @Solution
I ultimately was trying to compare Is DateX BEFORE or AFTER the Current Date.

Current Date was set with getInstance a ZERO BASED system.

I set DateX with -> .set (2014, 2, 27) a ONE BASED system thinking 2 represents Feb in a “NORMAL” calendar

when I compared TWO DATES, I was unknowingly using TWO different numbering systems.  

Moral -> When possible, use Constants .set (2014, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 28)

It makes the code more readable i.e. FEBRUARY instead of 1 which makes no sense because #1 appears to be January..

Answer (score 1):

Month in `Calendar` begins at 0, which means 0 is January, 1 is February, etc.

Java Date and Time API sucks. Use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

use constants in [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for month: [`Calendar.JANUARY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY) etc

For example:

```
cal.set(2014, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 27);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the description provided for MONTH Constant in Calendar Class.

```
Calendar.MONTH
```

public static final int MONTH

Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

So if you want to set the date in calendar than use below code snippet.

```
cal.set(2014, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 28);
```

I think it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now()
         .getYear()
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the industry-leading *java.time* classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

#### Parts

Interrogate for the parts as needed.

```
int dayOfMonth = ld.getDayOfMonth() ;
int month = ld.getMonthValue() ;
int year = ld.getYear() ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
In Calender class Jan as constant int is 0 , Feb is 1 ... .month constant int value is from 0,1,2..
```

Answer (score 0):

Let try this simple program:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
class CalendarExample {
public static void main(String args[]) {

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current Date : " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
System.out.println("Current Month : " + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
System.out.println("Current Year : " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.print("Current Time : ");
System.out.print(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":");
System.out.print(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":");
System.out.print(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
}
}
```

You get the o/p:

```
Current Date : 28
Current Month : 1
Current Year : 2014
Current Time : 11:18:3
```